# How to use getopts in any random order with long optional or non-optional argument first in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I have a script like

```
./sample.sh --add employeename -f firstname -a age -d detail
./sample.sh --add employeename  -a age -d detail -f firstname
./sample.sh --add employeename -d detail -f firstname
./sample.sh --del employeename
./sample.sh --update employeename -f firstname [age,detail are optional]
```

here,how could i use getopts for --add, --del, --update and i don't want to use getopt. Good suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: The `getopts` builtin can only handle single character options. Recommended reading: [BashFAQ/035](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035), [ComplexOptionParsing](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ComplexOptionParsing)

Comment: Thanks for the link -@BenjaminW.

Comment: Assuming you are required to specify exactly one of `add`, `del`, or `update`, consider making them a positional argument that *must* be given first, then parse the remaining arguments with an appropriate set of options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are really commands, not options, so should be regular positional arguments:

```
./sample.sh add employeename -f firstname -a age -d detail
./sample.sh add employeename  -a age -d detail -f firstname
./sample.sh add employeename -d detail -f firstname
./sample.sh del employeename
./sample.sh update employeename -f firstname [age,detail are optional]
```

which should come first; then the remaining options can be parsed using a command-specific set of options.

```
cmd=$1
shift
case $cmd in
  add) do_add "$@" ;;
  del) do_del "$@" ;;
  update) do_update "$@" ;; 
  *) echo "Unrecognized command: $cmd"
     exit 1
     ;;
esac

do_add () {
    name=$1
    shift
    while getopts "f:a:d:" opt "$@"; do
      ...
    done
    ...
}

do_del () {
    ...
}

# etc
```

Comment: Thanks chepner but I'm trying to pass the options for the getopts  to choose the case do i need to pass it as positional parameter if it the case how the next  options works here.

Comment: Updated to show `getopts` being used correctly. Inside a function, `getopts` will use the function's positional parameters, not the script's, but I've included `"$@"` as an explicit set of arguments to parse anyway.

Comment: The idea, though, is that you don't call `getopts` at all until *after* you have identified the first argument, and you only use it to parse the additional arguments, according to a parse string that is *defined* by the  first argument.

Comment: yeah @chepner   I'm clear untill the first argument  but just facing problem in passing  options for the cases . something like -f 'input' -a 'input' how the shift will takes place here.   sorry if question feels dump I'm very new to scripting :(

Comment: `shift` removes the first argument from the list of arguments. If you called the script with `add employeename -f name -a age`, then after you call shift the arguments include just `employeename -f name -a age`. `shift` is used to remove a leading argument (or arguments, if you use an optional numeric argument to `shift`) from the positional parameter, so that when you pass them to `do_add` or `do_del`, only the arguments you haven't examined or used yet get parsed by `get_opts`. Each of `do_add` et al. will use a different parse string for its call to `getopts`.

Comment: upvoted,really appreciate that @chepnear and works like charm :)